# Windows Forms DataGrid - Handel Click on expand button [+] on Row Header

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid

This is a question about `System.Windows.Forms.Datagrid`.

Is it possible to directly move to figure 2 without that **"Purchase Details link button"** after I click on the Expand Button? I mean I don't want that **"Purchase Details link button"**

Is that possible?

[image: Fig 1]

[image: Fig 2]

Comment: Make your row clickable, or add an event to handle the Row click, and then place your necessary code in there

Comment: @monstertjie_za I did know how to get the reference for the link button or the child table.

Comment: Do you need any further help?

Answer (score 1):

Legacy [DatGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) control has a private `NodeClicked` event which you can find it using reflection and subscribe for the event. This way you can catch click on a `+` at row header.

Then you can navigate to the related table of the clicked node using `NavigateTo` method of `DataGrid`.

This way, the navigation will be done immediately after you clicked on `+` at row header.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var eventsProperty = dataGrid1.GetType().GetProperty("Events",
                            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    EventHandlerList events = eventsProperty.GetValue(dataGrid1) as EventHandlerList;
    var eventsNodeClickedKeyField = dataGrid1.GetType().GetField("EVENT_NODECLICKED",
                            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
    object eventsNodeClickedKey = eventsNodeClickedKeyField.GetValue(null);
    events.AddHandler(eventsNodeClickedKey, new EventHandler(dataGrid1_NodeClicked));
}

private void dataGrid1_NodeClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as DataGrid;
    var point = grid.PointToClient(MousePosition);
    var hti = grid.HitTest(point);
    grid.NavigateTo(hti.Row, "RelationName");
}
```

Comment: @DonO I couldn't find a better workaround to do that, thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: By the way, I have ported the [DataGrid control to .NET 5](https://github.com/r-aghaei/System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid), you may modify the source code to add the desired event. I didn't test it 100%, but it could be a start point.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be like @monstertjie_za said. Add a click event to the row, with it open a new form where you can style all the fields to your liking.

optional you can just open the form from figure 2 with the click event.

Comment: i added a click even. i dont know how that link button reference. i did not find good example online to implement it

Comment: you have an primary ID, use this ID to link the forms together, as in your example, ID nr.50. In the click event to load the new window and add the ID like: form2 nwForm = new form2(ID);
In the new form use the ID of the order you clicked to show all the details.